# Associations access column values rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I have a Customer and Invoice Model. A customer has many invoices and an invoice belongs_to a customer. An invoice has many invoice items and Invoice items belong to an invoice

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :billing_address, :customer_currency, :email, :first_name, :last_name,    :mobile, :name, :payment_terms, :phase_type, :pays_vat
 validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :mobile, :billing_address, :payment_terms,    :phase_type, :customer_currency

has_many :invoices

validates :email, 
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => true, 
    :email_format => true
validates :name, :mobile, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Invoice Model

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :customer
 attr_accessible :approved_by, :due_date, :invoice_date, :terms, :customer_id, :customer

 validates :invoice_date, presence: true
 validates :due_date, presence: true
 validates :customer, presence: true
 has_many :invoice_items
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items
end
```

Invoice Items model

```
class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :invoice
 attr_accessible :amount, :description, :rate, :tax_amount
end
```

I have created an index page for Invoices where I want to list all invoices with their corresponding items however, the challenge I am having is how to access the amount in invoice items and display it in the index page

app/views/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Invoice ID </th>
  <th>Customer Name </th>
  <th>Invoice Date </th>
  <th>Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to invoice.id, invoice_path(invoice) %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.customer.name %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.invoice_date %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.invoice_items.amount %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="form actions">
<p>
    <%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
                new_invoice_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</p>
</div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

invoice.invoice_items.amount does not return that amount from Invoice_items for that invoice. Any ideas?

Below is my Invoices_controller index method

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

 def index
  @invoices = Invoice.includes(:customer, :invoice_items).all
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get amount of any elements using 
`invoice.invoice_items.count`

or
`invoice.invoice_items.size`

Comment: I do not want to get the number of invoice_items, I want to get the amount attribute of a given invoice from invoice_items when listing the invoices as shown in my index page of invoices

Comment: So try `invoice.invoice_items.attributes.keys.count`

Comment: trying this on the rails console returns NoMethodError: undefined method `invoice_items' for #<Array:0x007f9c82b8cb00>

Comment: In console you should run following: `$> invoice = Invoice.first` `$> invoice.invoice_items.attributes.keys.count` You can try it in View `<%= invoice.invoice_items.attributes.keys.count %>`

Comment: What i did was this. invoice.invoice_items.first.amount and it worked well.

Comment: Good job, but its a little strange to use such query in index.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

```
invoice.invoice_items.first.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate on `invoice_items` too, inside `@invoices` iterator

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to invoice.id, invoice_path(invoice) %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.customer.name %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.invoice_date %></td>

    <% invoice.invoice_items.each do |invoice_item| %>
      <td><%= invoice_item.rate %></td>
      <td><%= invoice_item.amount %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

adjust the table

Comment: Trying your example above shows this error NoMethodError: undefined method `invoice_items' for #<Array:0x007f9c84b391d8>

Comment: @zurik try invoice.invoice_items.each in the inner loop